# Python 3.2 question

Tags: python, urllib

I am using Python 3.2. I can import "urllib" library just like with 2.x version. But I can't find methods such as urlopen, urlretrieve, etc. What gives? How do I retrieve a webpage on v3.2?

I have tried to import urllib2 and urllib3 libraries. But my machine says it can't find those modules so not importable. Why these two newest libraries aren't supported in v3.2?

Comment: First question -> maybe reading the doc ? Second question -> "The languages, they are A-changin'"

Answer (score 9):

You should use `urllib.request`. Example [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#examples).

Answer (score 3):

[The 2.x docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) mention that in Python 3.x, the modules have been split into `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`. If you have some Python 2.x code and want to convert the modules to 3.x, you may be able to use the `2to3` tool.

Answer (score 3):

It was changed in the newer versions and was split up to now be `urllib.request`.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
```

A lot of what you're looking for is in the python library section on [urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html) and someone just mentioned an actual [example](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html#examples) from the documents that shows how the urllib.request.urlopen can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3000 represents a break with the past. Functions have been cleaned up, syntax has been modified, and the stdlib has been reorganized to provide a more logical grouping of tasks and abilities.

TL;DR: [Things change](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html).